# Analytical solution of a non convex function optimization

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I think this is probably obvious but I can not find a formal proof or any other reference on this online. My question is - If there exists a finite number of local minima/maxima of a non-convex function in the feasible region, and if we check each of them one by one and find the optimum minima/maxima (using SOSC?), can we call that global minima/maxima with sufficiency?

If YES, My follow up question on that is: I am trying to find an analytical solution to a problem. So is Lagrange multiplier/KKT a good way to go?

An example of objective function may be -> sin(x)*sin(y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the feasible region be $\mathbb{R}$ and consider $f(x) = x(x-1)(x+1)$.

There are finitely many local optimal but the global optimum doesn't exists.

Comment: Ok, what if the region is bounded in finite space? Take the example in my question and consider the feasible region is $x \leq ( 0, -\pi), y \leq (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

Comment: global optimum if exists must be a local optimum. So yup, you won't miss it out.